# Wordpress CSV import: title and content is importing but the meta data is not?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, csv, import

I am trying to import a CSV in WordPress using ajax the title and content is working but the post mete is not importing anything,

Following is the picture of the CSV file:
[image: CSV file image]

PHP code for import:

```
if(isset($_FILES['file'])){          
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
    $attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'file', 0 );
    $attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
    $fp = fopen($attachment_url, 'r');
    $csvReader = new yidas\csv\Reader($fp, [
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8'
    ]); 
    $firstRow = $csvReader->readRow();
    $remainingRows = $csvReader->readRows();
    foreach ($remainingRows as $key => $remainingRow){
        $cpt_id = array(
          'post_title'    => sanitize_text_field($remainingRow[0]),
          'post_content'  => sanitize_text_field($remainingRow[0]),
          'post_type'     => 'quotations',
          'post_status'   => 'publish'
        );
        wp_insert_post( $cpt_id );
        update_post_meta( $cpt_id, '_quotation_date', sanitize_text_field($remainingRow[1]) );
    }    
    fclose($fp);
    wp_send_json(array(  // send JSON back
      'message' => __( 'Quotation added', 'gd-povestea-mea' )
    ));
    wp_die();
}
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I think your code have some problems. you can try these codes.

```
if ( isset( $_FILES['file'] ) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
    $attachment_id  = media_handle_upload( 'file', 0 );
    $attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment_id );
    $fp             = fopen( $attachment_url, 'r' );
    $csvReader      = new yidas\csv\Reader( $fp, [
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8'
    ] );
    $firstRow       = $csvReader->readRow();
    $remainingRows  = $csvReader->readRows();
    foreach ( $remainingRows as $key => $remainingRow ) {
        $cpt_id  = array(
            'post_title'   => sanitize_text_field( $remainingRow[0] ),
            'post_content' => sanitize_text_field( $remainingRow[0] ),
            'post_type'    => 'quotations',
            'post_status'  => 'publish'
        );
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $cpt_id );
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_quotation_date', sanitize_text_field( $remainingRow[1] ) );
    }
    fclose( $fp );
    wp_send_json( array(  // send JSON back
        'message' => __( 'Quotation added', 'gd-povestea-mea' )
    ) );
    wp_die();
}
```

See more referance here,
[wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/)
[update_post_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/)

Comment: I will try and get back to you

Comment: Cant believe my silly mistake $post_id = wp_insert_post( $cpt_id ). Thanks.

Comment: it happens sometimes